# Solr Query - HTTP error 404 undefined field text

Tags: solr, lucene

I've got a Solr instance running on my Ubuntu machine using the default Jetty server that the Solr download comes with. Whenever I start Solr using

> java -jar start.jar

The server starts fine but there is always an exception thrown:

```
INFO: SolrDispatchFilter.init() done
Apr 12, 2012 2:01:56 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field text
```

As I said though, the server will still start and I can see the Solr admin interface. I defined my schema as follows.

```
<fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="phraseID" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="translation" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

I was also able to perform a JSON update - I submitted a sample array of data that was accepted. Up to this point everything is fine.

When I attempt to run a query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

It correctly returns all the data that I submitted in my sample earlier.

However, the moment I try to query using text, I receive an HTTP ERROR 404.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=fruit&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

--- returns ---

HTTP ERROR 400

Problem accessing /solr/select/. Reason:

    undefined field text
Powered by Jetty://
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Default solr configuration has defined some request handlers with defaults that match the default schema included in the solr tarball.

Check the request handlers defined in solrconfig and you might find that
`<str name="qf">` and other configuration values include some fields you haven't defined in the schema.

Also, check your schema.xml, that the default search field isn't set to **text** like this: `<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>`

Comment: The problem was the defaultSearchField - its set to "text" which I confused with the text type. I set the defaultSearchField to use "translation" (or whatever your field name is) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: In my case the problem was `<str name="qf">text</str>` instead of `<str name="qf">content</str>` in `solrconfig.xml` ("content" is set as `defaultSearchField` in `schema.xml`)

Comment: I have been searching for this answer for a couple of days, Thank you very much, indeed i had to vote up this awseome answer, though i wonder where is this been mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 50):

I had the same problem. 
In case there is no `<defaultSearchField>` in the `solrconfig.xml` file, look for the `/select` handler.

Within that you would find something like this

```
<str name="df">text</str>
```

That is the culprit. `df` means the default field and it, by default, and agreeably, quite stupidly, is set to a field called `text` which many might not have.

Remove it and replace it with whatever is to be your default search field.

Comment: @Arindam in my schema.xml i have added like this <field name="all_fields" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" />

<copyField source="title" dest="all_fields"/>  so that i can search all fields (HOPE ITS CORRECT) i followed your comment and changed solrconfig.xml as <str name="df">all_fields</str>. But my result shows empty what would be the reason ????? please help me

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem which appears either on a 404 answer sometimes as described above or as an exception in the jetty stack trace:

> SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field text
>
> > ```
> >    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1330)
> >    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1282)
> >    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrQueryParser.getWildcardQuery(SolrQueryParser.java:234)
> >    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:1414)
> > ```

I checked the defaultSearchField which is set to "content" (which seems ok for me)

Edit: I have in my schema.xml the following definition for type text (see no problem in it)

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField"
    positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory"
            protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: To complete my above post, I have a fieldTupe definition of "text" in my schema which is :

Comment: Look at the first answer. You probably need to edit your solrconfig.xml.

Answer (score 0):

The text field is composed of copies of another fields, as specified in the default schema.xml (when inserting a new document).

So, when we have the df "text" in the solrconfig.xml, and we make a search without specifying the field on the solr admin page such as: video. It will be looked up in the text field (which is composed of copies of another fields).

Answer (score 0):

This may not always be the case, but when I got a similar issue, it turned out that restarting the Solr server using *restart* command didn't suffice. Explicitly stopping the server with the *stop* command and then starting it using the *start* command actually did the trick. I did not require to edit any file.

P.S. My issue was with only /clustering not being accessible for my Solr core.