# Solr "Undefined field text"

Tags: java, tomcat, solr

I've recently upgraded my solr instance from 1,4 to 3.6. However, I now appear to be getting an "undefined field text" severe message in my logs whenever I update my index.

I do have text fields in my schema (which was valid as of version 1.4), but never previously had to be declared as a field type. Has this changed in 3.6?

My schema is here >>  http://pastebin.com/KrCVab0U

```
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field text
        at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1330)
        at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrQueryAnalyzer.getAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:408)
        at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrIndexAnalyzer.reusableTokenStream(IndexSchema.java:383)
        at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.getFieldQuery(QueryParser.java:574)
        at org.apache.solr.search.SolrQueryParser.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParser.java:206)
        at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:1429)
        at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:1317)
        at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:1245)
        at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:1234)
        at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:206)
        at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParserPlugin.java:79)
        at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:143)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:105)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.PingRequestHandler.handleRequestBody(PingRequestHandler.java:67)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: Actually, it appears the text field type is declared in my schema. Line 220 >> http://pastebin.com/KrCVab0U

Comment: Please see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130163/solr-query-http-error-404-undefined-field-text

Comment: As far as I see you don't have the field text declared, only the fieldType. The "undefined field type" error seems correct if you are trying to add content to a field called text, which you don't have in your schema. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can check this answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12094791/8148842) for a similar issue.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is not about field type "text". It is about field named "text".

You've changed the default field in config to "search_text". Please try renaming all references to "search_text" to "text". If this fixes the issue, then you know somewhere in the configuration you're referring to "text" field, possibly in solrconfig.xml as suggested in [Solr Query - HTTP error 404 undefined field text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130163/solr-query-http-error-404-undefined-field-text/10130462#10130462)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

i have this in my solrconfig.xml file.

```
<requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
 <lst name="invariants">
  <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
 </lst>
 <lst name="defaults">      
  <str name="echoParams">all</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

If you haven't added this in schema.xml then add it

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

This will solve your problem.

Thanks

Comment: in Solr6, a tiny difference: one need to add the "_ text _ " field to schema.xml (instead of "text"). The "_ text _ " field is used in the default solrconfig

Answer (score 3):

It just happened too me today. If your doing a query when the error occurs then you need to  double quoted the data in the query like this:

filepath:"data to be queried"

Comment: this is not going to solve the undefined field "text" error, did you get the same error as @lee-davis ?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when I sanitized the `fq` part of the query. After sanitizing, the solr received

```
...&fq=type\:Product&...
```

Although I have field named `type`, the error was saying “Undefined field text”.

When I removed the sanitization, the query was ok then:

```
...&fq=type:Product&...
```

The cause of the confusing error message was in solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <int name="rows">10</int>
    <str name="df">text</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 2):

in solr admin interface you can see currently working scheme then you can be sure if you are on the right path. below pictrues ilistruates

4.10.2 and higher version(suppose)

[image: solr.4.10.2]

lower versions than 4.10.2. you should use left side **Scheme** menu.

[image: solr.4.10.2]