# Solr Query - HTTP error 400 undefined field text

Tags: solr, solr6

In my solr query I have no problem in one server and another throwing error `error { "msg":"undefined field text",     "code":400}` for certain scenario.
I have referred [Solr Query - HTTP error 404 undefined field text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130163/solr-query-http-error-404-undefined-field-text) and many other referrences as well. But I couldn't find the reason why it is behaving like this.

`q=title:'food'` - returns result

`q=title:"food safety"` - returns result

`q=title:'food safety'` -  error { "msg":"undefined field text",     "code":400}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `debugQuery=true` to understand how your query looks after parsing.

```
q=title:'food safety'
```

After parsing query

```
"parsedquery_toString":"title:food text:safety"
```

Solr search for term 'food' in title field `title:food` and safety in `default` field called text. `text:safety`

Since it uses default field to search(text in this case), field `text` should be well defined in schema file.

Check your schema file modify accordingly. Example field definition for reference.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: I might be little late but can anyone tell me the reason for returning the correct results by one server? I am facing the same problem and one of the node is returning the correct results(parsing the query correctly) whereas all others are behaving differently. I mean if it's the searchquery error then it should have failed for all the nodes, right?